# Embed html tag in text in Angular6

Tags: angular

I'm new to angular programming. My requirement is to add link in text.
Ex: myStr:string='Thanks for Verification. Please `<a href="#">Login</a>`

in UI, its displaying html tag also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div [innerHTML]="myStr"></div>
```